# In AngularJS, how to force the re-validation of a field in a form when another value in the same form is changed?

Tags: angularjs, forms, validation, angularjs-directive

I have a form with few fields, however a select and an input field are coupled: the validation on the input depends on which value the user chooses in the select field.

I'll try to clarify with an example. Let's say that the select contains names of planets:

```
<select id="planet" class="form-control" name="planet" ng-model="planet" ng-options="c.val as c.label for c in planets"></select>
```

in the input I apply custom validation via a custom directive named "input-validation":

```
<input id="city" input-validation iv-allow-if="planet==='earth'" class="form-control" name="city" ng-model="city" required>
```

where this is the directive:

```
.directive('inputValidation', [function() {
  return {
    require: 'ngModel',
    restrict: 'A',
    scope: {
      ivAllowIf: '='
    },
    link: function(scope, elm, attrs, ctrl) {
      ctrl.$parsers.unshift(function(viewValue) {

        //input is allowed if the attribute is not present or the expression evaluates to true
        var inputAllowed = attrs.ivAllowIf === undefined || scope.$parent.$eval(attrs.ivAllowIf);

        if (inputAllowed) {
          ctrl.$setValidity('iv', true);
          return viewValue;
        } else {
          ctrl.$setValidity('iv', false);
          return undefined;
        }

      });
    }
  };
}])
```

The full example can be examined in Plnkr: http://plnkr.co/edit/t2xMPy1ehVFA5KNEDfrf?p=preview

Whenever the select is modified, I need the input to be verified again. This is not happening in my code. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I have done the same thing for validation of start-date on change of end-date. In the directive of start-date add watch for change of end-date and then call `ngModel.$validate()` in case end-date new value is defined.

```
    scope.$watch(function () {
        return $parse(attrs.endDate)(scope);
    }, function () {
        ngModel.$validate();
    });
```

The important part to take is call to `ngModel.$validate()` inside the directive.

**Note**
you should use $validators for custom validations above to work. [read here](http://blog.thoughtram.io/angularjs/2015/01/11/exploring-angular-1.3-validators-pipeline.html), $parsers is the old way - from angularjs 1.3 use $validators

[FIXED PLUNKER LINK](http://plnkr.co/edit/tst9NkWzjnwIl9Sz0XWO?p=preview)

Comment: Thanks for your input, I think I'm still missing some direction to get your suggestion to work. I forked my previous plunk here http://plnkr.co/edit/19YVCP3HOwWNaIi4fX71?p=preview and I'm trying to integrate your suggestions but it doesn't seem to work.

Comment: for my suggestion to work you need to add validation thru $validators and not thru $parsers. check my edited answer with a link about $validators

Comment: thank you so much, I missed the change about $validators, it saved me a lot of time.